# OnSend does not work in the outlook web app new design update (09-2018)

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

It is stated that in the new design update of the Outlook Web App:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Blog/Designed-to-be-fast-The-Outlook-on-the-web-user-experience-gets/ba-p/234909

certain features might not yet work:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Blog/List-of-features-not-yet-available-in-the-early-version-of-the/ba-p/240457

The `OnSend` hook functionality present for add-in development is not specifically stated, but we believe this also does not work in the new design version.

Is this correct or is it a bug (and should we file it on the userVoice page, since that appears to be the public bug tracker)

Comment: We are working to enable this feature in the new version soon.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT What does soon mean? I am also interested in that OnSend activation.

Comment: And what happens if you decide to roll out the new version (without any switch) without supporting OnSend? Will we, the development community be notified? if yes at all, how? @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT